# How to load XML file on iPhone using Unity?

Tags: ios, iphone, xml, unity-game-engine

I want to load XML files to generate levels of my game but on iPhone (or Android) it crash but on the editor it works fine.

Here is how I try to load my XML:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("Assets/XML/level1.xml");
level_root_node = xml.DocumentElement;
```

Please someone have already solved similar issues ?  I've tried to put my XMLs into "Assets/Resources/XML/level1.xml" but it doesn't work better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it fails is that on Android the resources are inside the APK file and can't be access directly as you are attempting.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LoadingResourcesatRuntime.html

You can use Resources.Load (path) to access a resource in a platform independent way.

Using Resources.Load() to load your XML asset, convert this to a string and pass it to the XMLDocument for parsing:

```
TextAsset textAsset = Resources.Load ("XML/level1.xml") as TextAsset;
xml.LoadXml(textAsset.text);
level_root_node = xml.DocumentElement;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It solved my issue but for a little precision, you don't have to put the file format in the Resources.Load(), I used it like that: TextAsset textAsset = Resources.Load ("XML/level1") as TextAsset;